# Accessing a UILabel via string Xcode identifier

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uilabel

If I have a `UILabel` on a `viewcontroller`, and have connected it to my swift class from the vc:

```
class RoomScheduleViewController: UIViewController {   
    @IBOutlet weak var bookingLabel8: UILabel!
```

How can I access this in a method? Like this:

```
    let hour = 8
    let labelToChange = "bookingLabel" + String(hour)

//Manipulate label e.g. labeltoChange.text = ".."
```

Also have an array like this: let

```
bookingLabelArray : [UILabel] = [bookingLabel8, bookingLabel9, bookingLabel10, bookingLabel11,bookingLabel12]
```

, was going to try loop through and check if the string is equal to the identifier but not sure how to do this?

Comment: you should used dictionary instead of array like` let  bookingLabels : [Int:UILabel] = [ 8: bookingLabel8,9: bookingLabel9]`

Comment: From what you have written, with a collection of UILabels - seems like a better choice would be to use a UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to map the "hour" to the label, e.g.

```
let labels = [8: bookingLabel8, 9: bookingLabel9 /* and so on */]

let hour = 8
if let labelToChange = labels[hour] {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment so I'll ask my questions while trying to answer.

For accessing your label in a method, you can just use the label like so:

```
bookingLabel8.text = "..."
```

But seeing as you hold an array of those labels I assume you mean a dynamic way of updating the text of a given label.

For that you can pass the label to the method as a param, like so:

```
func change(label: UILabel, to text: String) {
  label.text = text
}
```

that way you can call this function for whichever label you want, and use a loop to iterate over your labels and check on the identifier for which one you want to change:

```
change(label: bookingLabelArray[0], to: "new text")
```

but this seems like a weird way to do this, are you sure you need those labels as static UI components? This seems to be more of a use case for dynamic prototypes in a list/collection view. There are plenty of tutorials out there, this seems to be a good one [Prototype Cells](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/prototype-cells-table-view-ios-tutorial-ios10)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compose variable names at runtime.

A possible solution is to declare the labels as `IBOutletCollection`

```
@IBOutlet weak var bookingLabels: [UILabel]!
```

Connect all labels in Interface Builder to this outlet in the proper order

Then add a method to get the label for index (assuming label 8 is the first label in the collection)

```
func label(for hour: Int) -> UILabel? { 
   let index = hour - 8
   guard 0..<bookingLabels.count ~= index else { return nil }
   return bookingLabels[index]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for each loop:

If I understand correctly you want to catch the label with a certain text, lets call that certain text "your identifier":

```
bookingLabelArray.forEach { (label) in
        if label.text == "your identifier" {
            // do something with that label.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let hour = int ()
hour = 8

let bookingLabelArray = NSMutableArray()
let labelToChange = UILabel()

for i in 0..<4 // count till you want.. here take 4
{
   labelToChange = "bookingLabel" + String(hour + i)
   bookingLabelArray .add(labelToChange)


   //You can directly check label text
   if labelToChange.text == "yourIdentifier" {
        // do whatever you want.
    }


 // You can check from array
   if((bookingLabelArray.object(at: i) as! String) == "yourIdentifier" {
        // do whatever you want.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using IBOutlet Collections. For that you need to make '**outlet collection**' instead of **IBOutlet** like:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var bookingLabel: [UILabel]!
```

and later you can access them using index like an array. For example:

```
bookingLabel[8].text = "some text"
```

To make an outlet connection, select outlet collection for first label from interface builder and the connect each label to this outlet.

For more details on IBOutlet collections, follow this link:
[Outlet Collections](https://medium.com/@bfozdar/outlet-collections-a70b09ca61a3)

Answer (score 0):

If you set tag for labels you can access to label without IBOutlet.
Then you can do something like that:

```
func label(for hour: Int) -> UILabel? {
    return view.viewWithTag(hour) as? UILabel
}

let hour = 8 // bookingLabel8 needs tag 8
let labelToChange = label(for: hour)
labelToChange?.text = ".."
```

NOTE: this is simple but a dangerous solution because you can set the same tag for multiple subviews